# Are there other variables or objects in Java that like String objects will share a memory location or object reference if their value is equal?

Tags: java, string, reference

I have learned that the following variables will share the same place in memory in the JVM because their value is the same:

```
String banana = "yummy";
String strawberry = "yummy"; // banana == strawberry is true here
```

unless you provide one of them with "new" keyword like this:

```
String banana = "yummy";
String strawberry = new String("yummy"); // banana == strawberry is false
```

so that a new String object is forcibly created.

What I am wondering is, does this happen for any other objects than objects of the String class in Java?

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are other types where this applies.  Here's an example:

```
  Integer a = 42;
  Integer b = 42;
```

Instances of `Integer` in the range -128 to +127 produced by autoboxing are guaranteed to be the same object; see [JLS 5.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.7)  There are similar guaranteed for `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Short` and `Character` as well.  It can also apply for larger ranges of the above, and for `Long`, though this is platform specific.

In fact, what you are really asking is for examples of types `T` where `t1.equals(t2)` implies `t1 == t2` ... for some subset of `T`.  This is true for all array types, and any class types where `Object.equals` is not overridden.  Examples of the latter include all `enum` types, `java.lang.Class`, `java.lang.StringBuilder` and `java.lang.Object` itself.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is only applicable to String object.

Answer (score -1):

```
String banana = "yummy";
```

is a reference to "yummy" int the string pool.

```
String strawberry = new String("yummy");
```

create new object in the heap

String have method intern()

> Returns a canonical representation for the string object.

And this code prints true:

```
String banana = "yummy";
String strawberry = new String("yummy"); 
System.out.println(banana == strawberry.intern());
```

See [String javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Anyway use method equals for reference type objects.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question being asked.